# Quasar Dialog Plugin fails to load with "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'show')"

Tags: quasar-framework

I'm trying to open a dialog from a separate component using the Quasar Dialog Plugin method described [here](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog), but when I click the button that should open the dialog, I get the following error in the console:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'show')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add `ref="dialogRef"` to the opening `<q-dialog>` tag of my dialog component as shown [here](https://quasar.dev/vue-composables/use-dialog-plugin-component).

Here's a screenshot of the diff that got it working:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I was also missing the `@hide` handler and the `class="q-dialog-plugin"` class on the opening `<q-card>` tag, but those wouldn't have prevented the dialog from loading (I checked).

Comment: This fixed it for me too in a custom dialog.